# How can I update a field in Orchard via code

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.7

I'd created a content part "CompanyPart" which has a text field called "CompanyName". And added this content part to a content type Called "Company".

How Can I edit the value of the "CompanyName" field for a specific company via code. Or how Can I create a new Company with the company name set to "Company 1"

Comment: I think this will be helpful. http://orchard.codeplex.com/discussions/398270

Comment: the link is not working